# Comparison of proportions of successes. among machines

Tags: statistical-significance

I'm pretty new to statistical analysis, so sorry if this question is a little basic:

I have a $4\times 2$ table which looks like the following (it lists the number of successful/failed runs of four machines and the total number of times each machine was run):
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& Success & Failed & Total \\ \hline
 Machine\ A & 90 & 51 & 141\\ \hline
 Machine\ B & 31 & 23 & 54\\ \hline
 Machine\ C & 6 & 2 & 8\\ \hline
 Machine\ D & 152 & 75 & 227\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

As far as I have understood it so far, I can test whether there are statistically significant differences between the expected and the observed results with the Chi-squared test.

**My question would be:** Is there any statistcal test I could use that would tell me, for example: "The success rate for Machine A is statistically significant higher than that of the other machines and thus we can say that Machine A had the best performance"?

Or am I allowed to just directly compare the relative frequency of the success rates? So lets say for example: "Machine C performs the best because it has a success rate of $75\%$, which is the best of all four machines"?

I would be really glad for any input or advice on this, thank you!

Comment: The fist thing you can do is to produce a confidence interval for each rate of success .. and then compare, and see if they overlap or not ..

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I looked a little bit into that and came up with the following confidence intervals using the adjusted wald method:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& LBound& UBound\\ \hline
 Machine\ A & .55 & .71\\ \hline
 Machine\ B & .44& .69\\ \hline
 Machine\ C & .4& .93\\ \hline
 Machine\ D & .61& .73\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

So they all kind of overlap somehow. Would thus the interpretation be correct that there is no real winner-"Machine" in terms of success rate?

Comment: @MrSmith Checking overlap of confidence intervals is incorrect for two reasons: first, it doesn't achieve the desired confidence level; second--in this particular case--the intervals are not independent.  The underlying idea does work when properly applied and is called the [Tukey HSD test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tukey+hsd+score%3A2).  One can also formulate ANOVA as a linear regression and perform planned *post hoc* tests of the coefficients using that standard machinery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure `prop.test` in R makes a direct comparison
of the proportions of successes for the four 'machines'.

```
prop.test(c(90,31,6,152), c(141,54,8,227))

        4-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(90, 31, 6, 152) out of c(141, 54, 8, 227)
X-squared = 2.1824, df = 3, p-value = 0.5354
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4 
0.6382979 0.5740741 0.7500000 0.6696035 

Warning message:
In prop.test(c(90, 31, 6, 152), c(141, 54, 8, 227)) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Because of the large P-value, the preliminary verdict is
not to reject the null hypothesis.  That is, no differences
are found. However, the small counts for Machine 3, make
it impossible to find an accurate p-value.

However, this is roughly equivalent to a chi.squared test on the $4\times 2$ contingency table where rows are for machines and columns are for Success/Failure. As implemented in R,
it is possible to do a simulation, for which the P-value is more accurate. The final result still does not find statistically significant differences (5% level) among the four sample proportions of successes, on account of the P-value $0.6472 > 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
TAB = cbind(c(90, 31, 6, 152), c(51, 22, 2, 75))
chisq.test(TAB, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TAB
X-squared = 1.8077, df = NA, p-value = 0.6472
```

Very roughly speaking this mirrors the result in your comment with overlapping confidence intervals. However--even if these are 95% confidence intervals-- it is difficult to assess quantitatively the
significance of multiple overlaps among them. (See comment of @whuber.)

*Notes:* Without simulation, the chi-squared test gives a P-value about 0.6 (along with a warning message, not shown).

```
chisq.test(TAB)$p.val
[1] 0.6132557
```

The difficulty is low expected values for Machine 3. Because these are the only low expected values, statisticians might differ about the usefulness of the P-value without simulation.

```
chisq.test(TAB)$exp
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  91.699301 49.300699
[2,]  34.468531 18.531469
[3,]   5.202797  2.797203
[4,] 147.629371 79.370629
```

If we leave Machine 3 out of the analysis altogether, then we do
not find any significant differences:

```
TAB[c(1,2,4),]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   90   51
[2,]   31   22
[3,]  152   75  # formerly row 4

chisq.test(TAB[c(1,2,4),])

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB[c(1, 2, 4), ]
X-squared = 1.4481, df = 2, p-value = 0.4848
```

Finally, if you wanted to compare Machine A with
the other three machines taken together, you could
do a chi-squared analysis of a $2\times 2$ table with rows for A and BCD and columns for Success/Fail. You should get no warning messages about low counts from that test.

However, if you are going to do several such *ad hoc* tests on variants of the same data, you should work at
level 1% instead of 5% in order to avoid 'false discovery'. (See the Bonferroni method for details.)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer so thoroughly, actually learned quite a bit from it!